# Post comment authors name displays as admin user

Tags: comments

After approving a comment for a post, instead of showing the comment authors name or email, it instead shows the main admin's name for the site as the comment poster. Not sure how to make it so the commenter's name appears here instead.

This is my clients most recent blog post: https://thefreshperspective.net/ride-marketing-wave-dude/

Comment: have you made any edits to your theme? have you contacted the developer of your theme for help?

Comment: Adding to michael's comment, please also post the code for your comment template. There might be some misplaced function in it.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt replies guys. Jack, you said you would like me to post the code for the "comment template" - where would I find this?